# 502 Bad Gateway nginx - elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bad-gateway

I installed my application on the elasticbeanstalk infrastructure via code pipeline, but I get a 502 bad gateway error, and I use 3000 as the port. As listeners, my listener port is 80.

I keep the port with 3000 in my config file,

I did not specify this in the Software Configuration section, but others configs are arranged

Comment: Can you tell us what is your environment platform ? Can you show : configuration of ALB listeners ;  configuration of beanstalk part relative to the webserver ; any nginx custom configuration ; any log of nginx (/var/log/nginx) and logs about your running application (python, php...) ?